# Why is my findall replying with [] and some times displaying the data

Tags: python, findall

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import urllib.parse
import urllib.request
import re

i = ("james")

url = ("https://www.bing.com/search?q=" + i)

values = {'s': 'basics',
          'submit':'search'}
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)

data = data.encode('utf-8')
req = urllib.request.Request(url, data)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

cites = re.findall(r'<cite>(.*?)</cite>', str(respData))
print (cites)
```

Output
[]
the right response would be a bunch of links in list form
and it would some times display the results.

Comment: many pages use JavaScript to add items to page but `requests`/`BeautifulSoup` can't run JavaScript

Comment: first you should check what you have in `respData`. Maybe you get html with warning for bots or captcha to block your script.

Comment: there no data pointing to that

Comment: check first `print(respData)` or save it in file and open in browser to see if there is no warning.

Comment: BTW: if you imported `BeautifulSoup` then why don't you use it to get items from HTML? maybe it has something more then only `<cite>` - ie `<cite class="some name">`

Comment: it's used for something else and its the easiest way for me to do.

Comment: when I save `respData` in `temp.html` and open it in browser then it shows me empty page without any results. Maybe it blocks request (because it doesn't like bots) or it needs `user-agent` header to recognize browser and correctly format results. Normally Python sends request with user-agent like `python/2.x` instead of `Mozilla/5.0` (or similar).

Comment: when I use DevTool in Firefox/Chrome to test bing in browser then I don't see any `'s': 'basics', 'submit':'search'` in request - but only `search?q=james&go=Wyszukaj&qs=ds&form=QBRE`

Answer (score 1):

I can get data only if I use real full `User-Agent` header

```
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'
```

if I don't use `'User-Agent'` or use only `'Mozilla/5.0'` then I don't get results

Other elements wasn't needed but I keep it as comment in code.

Maybe it code will be used longer or more often then it may need cookies or other elements to works correctly.

---

Code which I used to test different `params`, `headers`, `Session`/`cookies`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
#import webbrowser

#s = requests.Session()

#headers = {
#    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'
#}

#response = s.get("https://www.bing.com", headers=headers)
#print(response.status_code)

params = {
    'q': 'james',
#    'go': 'Wyszukaj', # `Search` in my native, Polish language
#    'qs': 'ds',
#    'form': 'QBRE'
}

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0',
#    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
#    'Referer': 'https://www.bing.com',
}

response = requests.get("https://www.bing.com/search", params=params, headers=headers)
html = response.text

#with open('temp.html', 'w') as f:
#    f.write(html)
#webbrowser.open('temp.html')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
cites = soup.find_all('cite')
print(cites)
```

Comment: the thing is i got results sometimes

Comment: so it can means that bing blocks you because it knows that it script, not human. Your code has to behave more like human - it can may need to use Selenium to uses real browser which loads all data (images, css, js), loads pages in the same order -  first load main page, send request with random delay - but it can't be too small (human can visit two pages in 20ms) Or you may need also proxy servers to run code from different IP with different User-Agent to simulate different persons.

Answer (score -1):

If you get `[]` check your query with Bing using browser. If you see:

```
There are no results for <your query here>
Check your spelling or try different keywords
```

it's normal to get `[]` for this query using BeautifulSoup since there is no result returned.

Comment: there is results if you print raspdata that theres data and its a problem with re